# Software RAID never shuts down correctly

Tags: linux, raid, gentoo

Because I just love to push the boat out, I have setup my Gentoo Linux box on a software RAID 1 (mirroring), I have created a volume group with logical volumes for each of the major sections of the file system.  I have also put the root partition on one LV and got the system to work, which all the guides tell you not to do. However, when I shut down the system. the LVM never stops correctly, It's tricky to get the exact wording because the filesystems have already unmounted by this point, but it's along the lines of "unable to stop volume group 'main' device or resource busy"; main is the volume group which contains the root group.

Which causes a problem occasionally when I start up again.   Is their a way to fix this?

Comment: Upgrade to Debian, where that all works, and is even an easily supported thing in the installer (one of the "guided" partitioning options will even do it for you)... either that, or post a log of your shutdown messages so someone can spot the error.

Comment: "Up"grade to Debian?

Comment: I don't think changing to Debian (upgrade or not) is not an option for someone who prefers Gentoo.

Answer (score 1):

This [guy](http://stephan.kochen.nl/proj/initrd/) talks about making your own initrd.

Comment: Sadly, I have already made my own initrd, it basicly works fine, it's just this annoying one thing.